# Looping and clustering

Tags: r, algorithm

I have to admit this's too hard for me to do it on my own. I have to analyze some data and this step is crucial for me.

Data which I want to analyze:

```
> dput(tbl_clustering)
structure(list(P1 = structure(c(14L, 14L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 19L, 15L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 10L, 10L, 6L, 6L, 10L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 
27L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 28L, 28L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 29L, 29L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 20L, 20L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 7L, 26L, 26L, 24L, 24L, 
24L, 24L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 9L, 8L, 2L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 
12L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L), .Label = c("AT1G09130", 
"AT1G09620", "AT1G10760", "AT1G14610", "AT1G43170", "AT1G58080", 
"AT2G27680", "AT2G27710", "AT3G03710", "AT3G05590", "AT3G11510", 
"AT3G56130", "AT3G58730", "AT3G61540", "AT4G03520", "AT4G22930", 
"AT4G33030", "AT5G01600", "AT5G04710", "AT5G17990", "AT5G19220", 
"AT5G43940", "AT5G63310", "ATCG00020", "ATCG00380", "ATCG00720", 
"ATCG00770", "ATCG00810", "ATCG00900"), class = "factor"), P2 = structure(c(55L, 
54L, 29L, 4L, 70L, 72L, 18L, 9L, 58L, 68L, 19L, 6L, 1L, 16L, 
34L, 32L, 77L, 12L, 61L, 41L, 71L, 73L, 50L, 11L, 69L, 22L, 60L, 
42L, 47L, 45L, 59L, 30L, 24L, 23L, 77L, 45L, 12L, 47L, 59L, 82L, 
75L, 40L, 26L, 83L, 81L, 47L, 36L, 45L, 2L, 65L, 11L, 38L, 13L, 
31L, 53L, 78L, 7L, 80L, 79L, 7L, 76L, 17L, 10L, 3L, 68L, 51L, 
48L, 62L, 58L, 64L, 68L, 74L, 63L, 14L, 57L, 33L, 56L, 39L, 52L, 
35L, 43L, 25L, 27L, 21L, 15L, 5L, 49L, 37L, 66L, 20L, 44L, 69L, 
22L, 67L, 57L, 8L, 46L, 28L), .Label = c("AT1G01090", "AT1G02150", 
"AT1G03870", "AT1G09795", "AT1G13060", "AT1G14320", "AT1G15820", 
"AT1G17745", "AT1G20630", "AT1G29880", "AT1G29990", "AT1G43170", 
"AT1G52340", "AT1G52670", "AT1G56450", "AT1G59900", "AT1G69830", 
"AT1G75330", "AT1G78570", "AT2G05840", "AT2G28000", "AT2G34590", 
"AT2G35040", "AT2G37020", "AT2G40300", "AT2G42910", "AT2G44050", 
"AT2G44350", "AT2G45440", "AT3G01500", "AT3G03980", "AT3G04840", 
"AT3G07770", "AT3G13235", "AT3G14415", "AT3G18740", "AT3G22110", 
"AT3G22480", "AT3G22960", "AT3G51840", "AT3G54210", "AT3G54400", 
"AT3G56090", "AT3G60820", "AT4G00100", "AT4G00570", "AT4G02770", 
"AT4G11010", "AT4G14800", "AT4G18480", "AT4G20760", "AT4G26530", 
"AT4G28750", "AT4G30910", "AT4G30920", "AT4G33760", "AT4G34200", 
"AT5G02500", "AT5G02960", "AT5G10920", "AT5G12250", "AT5G13120", 
"AT5G16390", "AT5G18380", "AT5G35360", "AT5G35590", "AT5G35630", 
"AT5G35790", "AT5G48300", "AT5G52100", "AT5G56030", "AT5G60160", 
"AT5G64300", "AT5G67360", "ATCG00160", "ATCG00270", "ATCG00380", 
"ATCG00540", "ATCG00580", "ATCG00680", "ATCG00750", "ATCG00820", 
"ATCG01110"), class = "factor"), No_Interactions = c(8L, 5L, 
5L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 8L, 6L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 10L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 5L, 
5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
6L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 
8L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 
6L)), .Names = c("P1", "P2", "No_Interactions"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-98L))
```

To explain better what I want to achieve I will paste some rows over here:

```
        P1        P2 No_Interactions
1  AT3G61540 AT4G30920               8
2  AT3G61540 AT4G30910               5
3  AT1G58080 AT2G45440               5
4  AT1G58080 AT1G09795               9
5  AT1G58080 AT5G52100               7
6  AT5G04710 AT5G60160               6
7  AT4G03520 AT1G75330               5
8  AT3G58730 AT1G20630               5
9  AT3G58730 AT5G02500               5
10 AT3G58730 AT5G35790               5
```

First of all the new column `Cluster` has to be created. Next we focus only on two columns `P1` and `P2`. As you can see in first row we have two names `AT3G61540` and `AT4G30920` and that's our starting point (loop I believe will be necessary). We put the number 1 in `Cluster` column. Than we take first name `AT3G61540` and scan through both columns `P1` and `P2` if we find this name once again somewhere with other name than in first row we put number 1 as well in `Cluster`. Next we take second name from first row `AT4G30920` and do the same screening through whole data.

The next step will be to analyze next row and do exactly the same things. In that case in the next row we have exactly the same name for `P1` that means we don't need to screen it but the second name `AT4G30910` is different so would be great to screen with that one. The problem which appears here is that this row should be the `cluster 1` as well. The `cluster 2` starts with third row because we have completely new pair of names.

I am aware that's not so easy task and probably it has to be done in couple steps.

EDIT:
The output I would like to get:

```
       P1        P2 No_Interactions      Cluster
1  AT3G61540 AT4G30920               8      1
2  AT3G61540 AT4G30910               5      1
3  AT1G58080 AT2G45440               5      2
4  AT1G58080 AT1G09795               9      2
5  AT1G58080 AT5G52100               7      2
6  AT5G04710 AT5G60160               6      3
7  AT5G52100 AT1G75330               5      2 ### Cluster 2 because AT5G52100 was found in the row number 5 as a partner of AT1G58080
8  AT3G58730 AT1G20630               5      5
9  AT3G58730 AT5G02500               5      5
10 AT3G58730 AT3G61540               5      1 ## Cluster 1 because AT3G61540 was found in first row.
```

Comment: I'm unsure what you're asking. Should each cluster consist of observations with the same value for P1, or observations with the same value for P1 and P2?

Comment: You don't care about the value in third column `No_Interactions`. It just belongs to this data and I will use it for the other purpose. The only thing which has to be analyzed is the name. So the cluster is built only on the pairs between the names in two first columns.

Comment: I edited the question with desired output... Remember that just an example and my real data contains 100k rows...

Comment: btw, P1 and P2 differ in row 7 between your data example and desired output...

Comment: Hi, beware that your edit does not look like your original data.frame (have a look at line 10). So it's misleading for the reader! Better to use the same input. You will find a solution below.

Comment: Hi. I updated my answer with the wanted function. The clusters are attributed to a chain where any of P1 and P2 is common to another element of the chain.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed. I am using your codes. Both are usefull for my analysis. user1981275's code is quite simple but for some reason it doesn't work properly for my data. I was away from computer for some days so I can give a reward tomorrow. Started a bounty couple of minutes ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I corrected my initial answer and propose you a functional programming approach, using `Map` and `recursion` to find your clusters:

```
library(magrittr)

similar = function(u,v) if(length(intersect(u,v))==0) FALSE else TRUE

clusterify = function(df)
{ 
    clusters = df$cluster

    if(!any(clusters==0)) return(df)

    idx = pmatch(0, clusters)
    lst = Map(c, as.character(df[,1]), as.character(df[,2]))
    el  = c(as.character(df[idx, 1]), as.character(df[idx, 2]))

    K = lst %>%
        sapply(similar, v=el) %>%
        add(0)

    mask = if(any(clusters!=0 & K==1))

    if(any(mask))
    {
        cl = min(clusters[mask])
        df[K==1,]$cluster = cl
    }
    else
    {
        df[K==1,]$cluster = max(clusters) + 1
    }

    clusterify(df)
}
```

You can use it by `clusterify(transform(df, cluster=0))`

For example, the clustering operates correctly on your example, by taking cluster 9 (you can check other clusters):

```
subset(clusterify(transform(df, cluster=0)), cluster==9)
#          P1        P2 No_Interactions cluster
#25 AT5G19220 AT5G48300              10       9
#26 AT5G19220 AT2G34590               6       9
#27 AT5G19220 AT5G10920               6       9
#32 AT5G19220 AT3G01500               8       9
#33 AT5G19220 AT2G37020               5       9
#34 AT5G19220 AT2G35040               5       9
#92 AT4G22930 AT5G48300               5       9
#93 AT4G22930 AT2G34590               5       9
#94 AT4G22930 AT5G35630               5       9
#95 AT4G22930 AT4G34200               7       9
#96 AT4G22930 AT1G17745               5       9
#97 AT4G22930 AT4G00570               5       9
#98 AT4G22930 AT2G44350               6       9
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use library `igraph` to make an undirected graph in which you cluster connected composents:

```
library('igraph')

# make graph and cluster
g = graph.data.frame(tbl_clustering[,c('P1', 'P2')], directed=FALSE)
c = clusters(g)

# append cluster number to original data
tbl_clustering$cluster = sapply(as.vector(tbl_clustering$P1), function(x)c$membership[x])
```

This assigns clusters to the entries (here the first rows):

```
> head(tbl_clustering, 8)
         P1        P2 No_Interactions cluster
1 AT3G61540 AT4G30920               8       1
2 AT3G61540 AT4G30910               5       1
3 AT1G58080 AT2G45440               5       2
4 AT1G58080 AT1G09795               9       2
5 AT1G58080 AT5G52100               7       2
6 AT5G04710 AT5G60160               6       3
7 AT4G03520 AT1G75330               5       4
8 AT3G58730 AT1G20630               5       5
```

Comment: Nice, igraph is great! Less thinking and very functional :) Can you put the top 8 lines? I will do the same in my answer, at least to check our mutual result.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to divide your data set into equivalence classes. I have an implementation based on a algorithm in [Numerical Recipes](http://www.aip.de/groups/soe/local/numres/bookcpdf/c8-6.pdf). I have included the code below. It can be used as follows:

```
source("equivalence.R")
ids <- unique(c(levels(data[[1]]), levels(data[[2]])))
classes <- equivalence(ids, data[1:2])
data$class <- classes[match(data$P1, ids)]
```

**equivalence.R**

```
library(Rcpp)
Rcpp::sourceCpp('equivalence.cpp')

equivalence <- function(x, rules) {
  tmp <- unique(x)
  tmp <- tmp[!is.na(tmp)]
  a <- match(rules[[1]], tmp)
  b <- match(rules[[2]], tmp)
  sel <- !is.na(a) & !is.na(b)
  if (any(!sel)) {
    warning("Not all values in rules are present in x.")
    a <- a[sel]
    b <- b[sel]
  }
  res <- c_equivalence(as.integer(a)-1L, as.integer(b)-1L, 
    as.integer(length(tmp)))

  res[match(x, tmp)] + 1L
}
```

**equivalence.cpp**

```
#include <R.h>
#include <Rinternals.h>
#include <string>

extern "C" {
  // [[Rcpp::export]]
  SEXP c_equivalence(SEXP ra, SEXP rb, SEXP rn) {
    try {
      if (LENGTH(ra) != LENGTH(rb)) 
        throw std::string("Lengths of a and be do not match.");
      int* a = INTEGER(ra);
      int* b = INTEGER(rb);
      int  m = LENGTH(ra);
      int  n = INTEGER(rn)[0];
      SEXP classes = PROTECT(allocVector(INTSXP, n)); 
      int* cls = INTEGER(classes);
      //Initialize each element its own class.
      for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) cls[k] = k;
      //For each piece of input information...
      for (int l = 0; l < m; l++) {
        //Track first element up to its ancestor.
        int j = a[l];
        while (cls[j] != j) j = cls[j];
        //Track second element up to its ancestor.
        int k = b[l];
        while (cls[k] != k) k = cls[k];
        //If they are not already related, make them so.
        if (j != k) {
          cls[j] = k;
        }
      }
      //Final sweep up to highest ancestors.
      for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        while (cls[j] != cls[cls[j]]) cls[j] = cls[cls[j]];
      }
      UNPROTECT(1);
      return classes;
    } catch(const std::string& e) {
      error(e.c_str());
      return R_NilValue;
    } catch (...) {
      error("Uncaught exception.");
      return R_NilValue;
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here is a new answer, which goes some of the way.  Again, `dat` is the data frame.

```
Cluster <- rep(NA, length(dat[, 1])) #initialise
for(r in 1:length(Cluster)){
    if(identical(as.numeric(r), 1)){Cmatches <- matrix(c(as.character(dat[1, 1]), as.character(dat[1, 2])), 2, 1)}
    matched <- F
    for(cl in 1:length(Cmatches[1,])){
        if(sum(c(as.character(dat[r, 1]), as.character(dat[r, 2])) %in% Cmatches[, cl]) != 0){
            #add P1 and P2 from this row to the cluster which it matches
            Cmatches <- rbind(Cmatches, matrix(c(if(cl != 1){rep("", (cl - 1)*2)}else{character(0)}, as.character(dat[r, 1]), as.character(dat[r, 2]), if(cl != length(Cmatches[1,])){rep("", (length(Cmatches[1, ]) - cl)*2)}else{character(0)}), 2, length(Cmatches[1,]), byrow = F))
            matched <- T
            Cluster[r] <- cl
        }
    }
    if(!matched){
        #add a new cluster, because doesn't match any existing
        Cmatches <- cbind(Cmatches, c(c(as.character(dat[r, 1]), as.character(dat[r, 2])), rep("", length(Cmatches[, 1]) - 2)))
        Cluster[r] <- length(Cmatches[1,])
    }
}
```

After this, you would take the `Cmatch` matrix and then check for matches between the clusters using `if(sum(match(Cmatch[, cl1], Cmatch[, cl2], incomparables = ""), na.rm = T) != 0)` (where `cl1` and `cl2` are cluster numbers to be compared).  If that test was true, then those clusters should be grouped.

```
Cmatched <- rep(NA, length(Cmatches[1,]))
for(cl in 1:(length(Cmatches[1,]) - 1)){
    for(cl2 in (cl + 1):length(Cmatches[1,])){
        if(sum(match(Cmatches[, cl], Cmatches[, cl2], incomparables = ""), na.rm = T) != 0){
            if(is.na(Cmatched[cl])){
                Cluster[Cluster == cl2] <- cl
                Cmatched[cl2] <- cl
            }else{
                Cluster[Cluster == cl2] <- Cmatched[cl]
                Cmatched[cl2] <- cl
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I think that there is your answer.  Then just `dat <- cbind(dat, Cluster)`.

Comment: To be honest it is possible that some rows might belong to multiple clusters. I didn't mention about that because I didn't know it's doable... If you can do that I would appreciate to have those two codes!

Comment: Okay, looking at your additional comments, it seems that this wouldn't go far enough.  You would need to create an additional data frame or set of vectors that would store all the possible match values for each cluster.  The code would need to search these to determine if the row in question belonged to each cluster.  You would also need to check back again at previously assigned rows: clusters may be merged in the course of execution.

Comment: In response to your comment, I think that seeing your comments above, this wouldn't be possible. But as I say, clusters may become grouped together during the course of execution.  It's quite possible that the result could be everything belonging to one big cluster!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to do categorical clustering. You should look into [k-modes](http://www.irma-international.org/viewtitle/10828/) clustering which is an an extension of [k-means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering). The k-modes algorithm mirrors the steps of k-means. Here is the outline provided in the paper.

> 1. Randomly select k unique objects as the initial cluster centers (modes).
> 2. Calculate the distances between each object and the cluster mode; assign the object to the cluster whose center has the shortest distance to the object; repeat this step until all objects are assigned to clusters.
> 3. Select a new mode for each cluster and compare it with the previous mode. If different, go back to Step 2; otherwise, stop

There are other issues discussed like k-prototypes (for mixing categorical with numerical data), fuzzy k-modes (for assigning cluster membership), and initialization of k-modes.