# Building the clusters based on the "partnership"

Tags: r

Some time ago I did similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31453974/looping-and-clustering) but unfortunately the approach which I've used there didn't give me any promising results. I came with an idea how to do it in a different way. So here I am.

Of course example data:

```
structure(list(Name1 = c("Mazda RX4", "Mazda RX4", "KIA Ceed", 
"Mazda RX4 Wag", "KIA Ceed", "Valiant", "KIA Classic", "Mazda RX4", 
"Dacia", "Merc 280", "Duster 360", "Merc 230"), Name2 = c("Mazda RX4 Wag", 
"Merc 230", "KIA Sport", "Merc 230", "KIA Classic", "Merc 230", 
"KIA Sport", "Merc 240D", "Mazda RX4 Wag", "Merc 450SE", "Valiant", 
"Duster 360")), .Names = c("Name1", "Name2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
12L))
```

This data frame contains only two columns. The original data has more but this time I will focus only on those columns.

Just to show how exactly I would like to cluster those guys I will put a desired output:

```
structure(list(Name1 = c("Mazda RX4", "Mazda RX4", "KIA Ceed", 
"Mazda RX4 Wag", "KIA Ceed", "Valiant", "KIA Classic", "Mazda RX4", 
"Dacia", "Merc 280", "Duster 360", "Merc 230"), Name2 = c("Mazda RX4 Wag", 
"Merc 230", "KIA Sport", "Merc 230", "KIA Classic", "Merc 230", 
"KIA Sport", "Merc 240D", "Mazda RX4 Wag", "Merc 450SE", "Valiant", 
"Duster 360"), cluster = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3
)), .Names = c("Name1", "Name2", "cluster"), row.names = c(NA, 
12L), class = "data.frame")
```

As you can see from the ouput I would like to cluster cars depending on the partner which can be find in the second column. So if the cars in one row shares the same "partner" in the next column they should be clustered together.

And how it looks in the table form with a little bit of explanation:

```
           Name1         Name2 cluster
1      Mazda RX4 Mazda RX4 Wag       1  ## Two Mazda's same cluster
2      Mazda RX4      Merc 230       1  ## First Mazda with another partner
3       KIA Ceed     KIA Sport       2  ## Ceed together with Sport
4  Mazda RX4 Wag      Merc 230       1  ## Second Mazda with the same partner
5       KIA Ceed   KIA Classic       2  ## Ceed together with Classic
6        Valiant      Merc 230       3  
7    KIA Classic     KIA Sport       2  ## And of course Classic with Sport
8      Mazda RX4     Merc 240D       0  ## First Mazda with another Merc but can't be clustered together in the cluster number 1 because the second Mazda doesn't share this "partner".
9          Dacia Mazda RX4 Wag       0  ## Similar situation but just second Mazda
10      Merc 280    Merc 450SE       0
11    Duster 360       Valiant       3
12      Merc 230    Duster 360       3
```

It's just simple example what I would like to achieve. Of course according to my original data it may happen that some pairs of cars will be members of different clusters. Cluster numbers can be separated by coma or the another column can be created if necessary. 
It's not obligatory to set 0 for the pairs which cannot be clustered with anything else. They can just form a cluster with single row. I will not analyze it anyway.

I hope that I was able to explain exactly what I would like to achieve. Creative ideas are more than welcome.

Of course I would like to start the bounty for the answer which satisfies me like I did in previous thread.

Comment: Its not clear how your clusters are derived in the output. Can you show some calculation for how you arrived at the cluster values? "As you can see from the ouput I would like to cluster cars depending on the partner which can be fond in the second column" - what exactly do you mean by this?

Comment: Agree with @Gaurav, could you detail more the process of how you determine the clusters? For instance, is it important that you have different model from the same brand or brand does not matter? Finally and most importantly: **what is the aim of this**? What would you like this analysis to tell you and what do you want to use the results for (that may help us to suggest different type of clustering and/or point you to a different type of analysis altogether)?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to do complete-linkage clustering. Is that true? If so you sould be able to convert your pairs into a matrix of zeros and ones and run hclust on it.

Comment: Maybe if you take a look on the previous thread which I created it will help you to understand the concept. It is hard to explain for me what's the main goal but I am working on the interactions between genes. We already developed different approaches to test those interactions. The problem which we are facing right now is that there is too many of them so we would like to find the way how to cluster them and assign to specific pathway. In that case I would like to create clusters which contain at least 3 different genes and all of them interact which each other.

Comment: @ShaxiLiver I think your whole problem is clearly better defined by the last sentence of your comment "I would like to create clusters which contain at least 3 different genes and all of them interact which each other", what's hard is having same gene in multiple clusters

Comment: As I mentioned we have thousands of rows which have to be analyzed like that so I can imagine that such situation may happen (I mean that pair of genes can be a part of different clusters). I believe that it might be hard to do or even impossible.

Comment: @ShaxiLiver And what was not working on previous thread ? The accepted answer sounds correct and there's no comment on what is wrong with it... (just no promising result at start of this question...)

Comment: It was correct because it was different approach. In previous thread it was just about taking each of the pairs/rows and find potential interacting  genes. It that case it has to be like that A interact with B, than B interact with C, so A has to interact with C as well to be clustered together. Previous approach was just about finding all genes interacting with A, and than potential partners of first interactor of A, so that could be a genes which have nothing in common with A... Now everything has to interact with everything in the same cluster.

Comment: Ok, I didn't get this in the other thread, but understood properly this one. I'll see if I can get to something

Comment: Have you tried checking out Bioconductor? Gene network analysis is something well studied, I'm sure there are lots of methods out there... you may also want to try and ask on [Biostars](https://www.biostars.org/), where you may get a more specific answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the comments, "I would like to create clusters which contain at least 3 different genes and all of them interact which each other."

This description would appear to correspond to the definition of a clique in graph theory. That is, you appear to be seeking all cliques of size 3 or larger.

[image: cliques]

So with your sample `data`

```
library(igraph)
g<-graph.data.frame(data,directed=FALSE)
(q<-cliques(g,min=3))
#> [[1]]
#> + 3/12 vertices, named:
#> [1] Mazda RX4     Mazda RX4 Wag Merc 230     
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> + 3/12 vertices, named:
#> [1] KIA Ceed    KIA Classic KIA Sport  
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> + 3/12 vertices, named:
#> [1] Valiant    Duster 360 Merc 230
```

You recognize that any edge could belong to more than one clique, so I have created one column per clique with a flag for beloning to that clique.

```
ind<-t(apply(data,1,function(r) sapply(q,function(i) all(as.character(r) %in% names(i)))))
(d1<-cbind(data,ind))
```

```
           Name1         Name2     1     2     3
1      Mazda RX4 Mazda RX4 Wag  TRUE FALSE FALSE
2      Mazda RX4      Merc 230  TRUE FALSE FALSE
3       KIA Ceed     KIA Sport FALSE  TRUE FALSE
4  Mazda RX4 Wag      Merc 230  TRUE FALSE FALSE
5       KIA Ceed   KIA Classic FALSE  TRUE FALSE
6        Valiant      Merc 230 FALSE FALSE  TRUE
7    KIA Classic     KIA Sport FALSE  TRUE FALSE
8      Mazda RX4     Merc 240D FALSE FALSE FALSE
9          Dacia Mazda RX4 Wag FALSE FALSE FALSE
10      Merc 280    Merc 450SE FALSE FALSE FALSE
11    Duster 360       Valiant FALSE FALSE  TRUE
12      Merc 230    Duster 360 FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Or, you could present them in a list in each row of the data.frame.

```
(d2<-cbind(data,clique=I(as.list(apply(ind,1,which)))))
```

```
           Name1         Name2 clique
1      Mazda RX4 Mazda RX4 Wag      1
2      Mazda RX4      Merc 230      1
3       KIA Ceed     KIA Sport      2
4  Mazda RX4 Wag      Merc 230      1
5       KIA Ceed   KIA Classic      2
6        Valiant      Merc 230      3
7    KIA Classic     KIA Sport      2
8      Mazda RX4     Merc 240D       
9          Dacia Mazda RX4 Wag       
10      Merc 280    Merc 450SE       
11    Duster 360       Valiant      3
12      Merc 230    Duster 360      3
```

Comment: I can stop scratching my head, this answer is far most efficient than the one I was working on :)

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Of course the bounty will start soon. For some data this error appears, when I am trying to second code. It never appears for the first one..: `Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 84, 3`. Do you know that might be the reason ?

Comment: Make sure you have the `I(...)` wrapping, which tells the data frame to treat the list "as is". I can generate a similar error when dropping it, but I cannot know without the data.

Comment: By the way, bounties are generally _not_ needed for interesting questions, which are their own reward. The main problem with this question is that it was harder to determine what you were asking than it was to write up a solution. Pictures are usually very helpful in conveying ideas and help grab attention.

Answer (score 3):

Probably far less efficient, but posting for advice/remarks:

```
cars <- structure(list(Name1 = c("Mazda RX4", "Mazda RX4", "KIA Ceed", 
 "Mazda RX4 Wag", "KIA Ceed", "Valiant", "KIA Classic", "Mazda RX4", 
 "Dacia", "Merc 280", "Duster 360", "Merc 230"), Name2 = c("Mazda RX4 Wag", 
 "Merc 230", "KIA Sport", "Merc 230", "KIA Classic", "Merc 230", 
 "KIA Sport", "Merc 240D", "Mazda RX4 Wag", "Merc 450SE", "Valiant", 
 "Duster 360")), .Names = c("Name1", "Name2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 12L))

# Add the cluster number column to df, first row being cluster 1
cars$cluster <- c(1,rep(0,nrow(cars)-1))

# First cluster, we have to start somewhere
clusters <- list(c(paste0(cars$Name1[1]),paste0(cars$Name2[1]))) # Side note, use of paste0 for a readable output in case of factorized dataframe


# Now the ugly part, loop over the df starting at row 2
for (i in 2:nrow(cars)) {
  # Get the cars name in a more easy variable name
  c1 <- paste0(cars$Name1[i])
  c2 <- paste0(cars$Name2[i])
  # boolean to know if a new cluster have to be created
  found <- F

  # Check if first car is referenced somewhere in a cluster
  if (c1 %in% unlist(clusters)) {
    # It is, loop over the cluster list to find in wich
    for (j in 1:length(clusters)) {
      cl <- clusters[[j]] # Same shortcut var for the cluster
      if (c1 %in% cl) { # Find which cluster c1 is part of
        others <- cl[cl != c1] # Now get the other cluster members
        # Now check if the partner exists in df with relation to 1 of the others 
        if ( any( (cars$Name1 %in% others & cars$Name2 == c2)  
                | (cars$Name2 %in% others & cars$Name1 == c2) 

             )
           )
        {
          if (!c2 %in% cl) {
            clusters[[j]] <- append(cl,c2) # Update the cluster with partner car if not already present

          }
          found <- T # Set the boolean
          break # We can stop looping in the cluster list now
        }

      }
    }
  } else if (c2 %in% unlist(clusters)) { # Same as previous block with c1 and c2 swapped
    for (j in 1:length(clusters)) {
      cl <- clusters[[j]]
      if (c2 %in% cl) {
        others <- cl[cl != c2]
        if ( any( (cars$Name1 %in% others & cars$Name2 == c1) 
                | (cars$Name2 %in% others & cars$Name1 == c1) 
             )
           )
        {
          if (!c1 %in% cl) {
            clusters[[j]] <- append(cl,c1)
          }
          found <- T
          break
        }
      }
    }
  }
  # If the pair could be related to a cluster, update the df and got to next row
  if (found == T) { 
    cars$cluster[i] <- j
    next
  }
  # We didn't found a match, just create a new cluster with the pair and udpate the df
  clusters[[length(clusters)+1]] <- c(c1,c2)
  cars$cluster[i] <- length(clusters)
}
```

Wich output:

```
> cars
           Name1         Name2 cluster
1      Mazda RX4 Mazda RX4 Wag       1
2      Mazda RX4      Merc 230       1
3       KIA Ceed     KIA Sport       2
4  Mazda RX4 Wag      Merc 230       1
5       KIA Ceed   KIA Classic       2
6        Valiant      Merc 230       3
7    KIA Classic     KIA Sport       2
8      Mazda RX4     Merc 240D       4
9          Dacia Mazda RX4 Wag       5
10      Merc 280    Merc 450SE       6
11    Duster 360       Valiant       3
12      Merc 230    Duster 360       3
```

Or in cluster list view:

```
> clusters
[[1]]
[1] "Mazda RX4"     "Mazda RX4 Wag" "Merc 230"     

[[2]]
[1] "KIA Ceed"    "KIA Sport"   "KIA Classic"

[[3]]
[1] "Valiant"    "Merc 230"   "Duster 360"

[[4]]
[1] "Mazda RX4" "Merc 240D"

[[5]]
[1] "Dacia"         "Mazda RX4 Wag"

[[6]]
[1] "Merc 280"   "Merc 450SE"
```